# best SEO header status to redirect index for user languages

Tags: php, redirect, seo, google-search-console

I have a multi-language site

```
www.Sooran.com
food.sooran.com/en/      // for global
food.sooran.com/fa/      // for persian user
```

first page of Site(index.php) designed based on ip redirects the user's language

But late in my search engines have reduced by 10 times.

To my mind I should use a header location

Comment: i used 301,but not good

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Don't

Just don't redirect users.

If a user is coming from Persia and wanna see EN version he won't be able to?

As Google says: "let user chooses". They did a very good article about the good way to design a homepage for international users: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2014/05/creating-right-homepage-for-your.html

Moreover, redirect based on IP is dangerous. Google does not have spiders in whole countries in the world so he might not see the different behaviors.

### If you really have to : 302 redirect

(client force you to do it or you just do not understand users hate to be redirected or ...)

Use a HTTP 302 status to redirect.

Why ?
Because 302 means both URLs exist. Thus Google will keep both URL indexed.

Comment: What if www.mysite.com and www.mysite.com/en/ both work and have the same content? Wouldn't it be wise to redirect 301 www.mysite.com (without /en/) to www.mysite.com/en/ so I don't have duplicate content?

Comment: Shortest answer: if you really have this case, 301 redirect /en/ to the root (because it is preferable to have your content on root). But if you can, I would suggest you to publish something different on root and on /en/